# Bash control flow skips to else no matter what

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a small script to switch branches for me. I have only ever written in bash once long ago. In the following code, the `if`s and `elif`s are skipped, and no matter what I input as `$1`, it always skips to the `else`. Ive looked at various examples and nothing is working, though it should be.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1 " == "-p" ]
    then
        cd ui;
        git checkout p_4.1;
        cd ../services;
        git checkout p_4.1;
        cd ../application;
        git checkout p_4.1;
        cd ..;
elif [ "$1 " == "-b" ]
    then
        cd ui;
        git checkout b_.1;
        cd ../services;
        git checkout b_.1;
        cd ../application;
        git checkout b_.1;
        cd ..;
elif [ "$1 " == "-g" ]
    then
        cd ui;
        git checkout g_.1;
        cd ../services;
        git checkout g_.1;
        cd ../application;
        git checkout g_.1;
        cd ..;
elif [ "$1 " == "-j" ]
    then
        cd ui;
        git checkout j_.1;
        cd ../services;
        git checkout j_.1;
        cd ../application;
        git checkout j_.1;
        cd ..;
else
    echo "No Command Known!"
 fi
```

I have absolutely no idea why it isn't working.

Comment: You might want to look at `case $1 in ...` or `getopt` or `getopts`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The spaces inside the double quotes are significant, and all `"$1 "` should be `"$1"` (no trailing space).

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a space after each $1. I believe that is your problem.